# Google Play SubscriptionNotification - SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED event initial state is SUBSCRIPTION_STATE_CANCELED with systemInitiatedCancellation

Tags: android, node.js, google-play, google-play-developer-api

This happens on our production server. We have a subscription based product and we listen to Google Play's Real-time developer notifications on our node backend. We use `purchases.subscriptionsv2.get` to parse the notification.

Recently we notice that there is couple **SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED** notifications from this one user, the `subscriptionState` of the purchase is **SUBSCRIPTION_STATE_CANCELED** from the beginning, with `canceledStateContext` set to `{"systemInitiatedCancellation": {}}` when we first receive the notification.

What does this mean? I mean usually a SUBSCRIPTION_PURCHASED notification comes with SUBSCRIPTION_STATE_ACTIVE and we ack the notification. From [Google's doc](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/lifecycle/subscriptions#new-auto) it says "Make sure that the value of the subscriptionState field is SUBSCRIPTION_STATE_ACTIVE." In this case what should we do? Why the system cancel the subscription from the beginning?

We use `purchases.subscriptionsv2.get` to parse the notification. But if we parse the same notification with `purchases.subscriptions.get`, it shows the `paymentState` is 1 which means payment received, and `cancelReason` is also 1 which just indicates it is canceled by the system. I am not sure if paymentState always stays 1 or it changes from 0 to 1 (pending to received), there is no other notifications we received.

Please advise me what this scenario means and what the best practice should be here, Thanks!